# Ionic 5 Angular 10 strange button disabled behaviour

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have strange behaviour with **Ionic 5 Angular 10**.

My app have **notification** feature that allow user to navigate to specific page based on notification type. Unfortunately in **Android device** i need to separate notification action based on app state **(background or foreground)**. When app is in **background** the **Push Notification** shown, but when App running in **foreground** i modified my function using **Local Notification** because idk why the **Push Notification** did’nt work in **Android foreground**.

Here is my **code**.

**TS**

```
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from ‘@angular/router’;
import { ActionPerformed as LocalNotificationActionPerformed, LocalNotifications } from “@capacitor/local-notifications”;

constructor (private router: Router) {}
LocalNotifications.addListener(‘localNotificationActionPerformed’, (res: LocalNotificationActionPerformed) => {
    let params: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: {chatToEmployeeId: res.notification.extra.employeeId}
    }
    this.router.navigate([’/friend-list/chat’], params);
})

isDisabled() {
    return this.newMsg == ‘’ ? true : false;
}
```

I have a button with property **[disabled]** that using function to return **true** or **false** based on some condition.

**HTML**

```
<ion-textarea placeholder=“Type a message…” id=“newMsg” name=“newMsg” class=“message-input” rows=“1” autoGrow=“true” style=“max-height: 100px;” maxLength=“500” ngModel [(ngModel)]=“newMsg”>

<ion-button id=“sendMsg” [disabled]=“isDisabled()” class=“msg-btn” (click)=“sendMessage()”>
```

When user tap the notification from **Push Notification**, it’s working fine. But, when user tap from **Local Notification**, the button always **disabled**, idk why, i’ve tried many different ways, but no one works for me.

Comment: Find out why this.newMsg has no value. Most likely it is undefined in case of local notification.

Comment: i assign this.newMsg with empty string when page load